# Store Hebrew Dates in a SQL Database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, date, database-design

I am designing a database for use with a Ruby on Rails application. For a given object, I need to access the date of an event in both the [Gregorian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) format and the [Hebrew calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar) equivalent. I can easily convert between the two formats, but the issue is that in the Hebrew calendar, *the date changes at sunset*, not midnight. Therefore, I'll need to either store two separate dates, or store a Gregorian date and a separate boolean field, `after_sunset`. Then, whenever I need to access the Hebrew date, I'll need to query for both fields, convert the date, and if `after_sunset==true`, increment the date.

Which of these options is considered "better"?

And, if I store the Hebrew date separately, is it best to  store it as a String, an Integer, or can I use a regular Date?

Comment: So for every event you know the date and whether its before or after sunset, but not the exact time or time span?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an after_sunset flag you store a Gregorian date and add all the additional information needed to know the Hebrew date.

With two dates you would store the two dates explicitely. However, to have data consistent you would install a check constraint to ensure that the dates match. This is because the two dates share part of their information (redundancy). This means the data is not normalized.

For this reason, to have data normalized in your database (and thus not having to install a check constraint to keep the data consistent) the first approach is better. Store the date plus an after- sunset flag.

Answer (score 0):

Store the date in UTC and also store in unix format
You can use conversion function based on the type
This will allow your database to support other date time formats easily in the future

Comment: I will not need any other calendar type.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are going back to the dawn of time, I think I would simply have a many-year lookup table of UTC datetimes and Hebrew dates where the UTC column is the first second of the Hebrew day in a specific time zone (Greenwich?).

Conversions are a quick binary search,

```
 SELECT hebrew_date FROM hebrew_gregorian_lookup
 WHERE some_input_time >= gregorian_cutoff
 ORDER BY gregorian_cutoff DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If you index and cluster the lookup table on `gregorian_cutoff`, it should be very quick, even for 100 years. (If your RDBMS has a way to force a table into RAM, even better.) Also depending on your RDBMS, you may be able to wrap this in a function/procedure with no loss of efficiency.

I suggest storing the Hebrew date not as a string but as a record of three shorts, day, month, year. You can have a tiny lookup table for month to string, or perhaps use an enumeration. That will give you some flexibility in formatting, e.g., Hebrew characters vs. Latin in the output.